# asp.net mvc3, Authorize attribute redirects to wrong login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, authorize

I have a page that needs to be secured.  I add `[Authorize]` attribute to that action method.  if you are not logged in, you will be redirect to the login page everytime you visit that secure page.

it works except I rename logon action to login , but applicaiton still redirects user to logon action. its no long there, I rename it,  how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

In your Web.config file change the forms loginUrl.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Controller/Action" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `loginUrl` in the [`<forms />` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in Web.config.