# Wrong redirection while using authorize attribute. Redirects to account/login instead of account/logon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am facing an un-recognized error in Asp.net MVC 3.0 while using authorize attribute.

**accountController**

```
 public ActionResult LogOn()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

**testController**

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
       return View();
 }
```

**Webconfig**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="1440" />
</authentication>
```

now while accessing the http://www.abc.com/test

Error:  http://www.abc.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2ftest

it should redirect to account/logon but its not. Why? 
For solution i have just added a new route url in global.asax.cs `routes.MapRoute("auth", "account/login", new { Controller = "account", action = "logon" });`

For reference i have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238437/why-does-authorizeattribute-redirect-to-the-login-page-for-authentication-and-au) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751500/asp-net-mvc3-authorize-attribute-redirects-to-wrong-login-page)

Is this a bug or something is missing from my side?

Comment: The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/Login

Comment: try ../Account/Login or ../../Account/Login

Comment: Sebastian i think this will not solve the purpose as the url defined in webconfig is "~/Account/LogOn" and for everything else [authorize] handles the request.

Comment: i remember seeing something like this, it had something to do with the webmatrix dlls getting pushing into the bin folder in my project, once i removed those, it started working again, bizarre

Comment: Slicksim Bingo!! yes i found webmatrix dll in the bin folder. it works after deleting those. BUT now the question is How did they arrived ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity(v=vs.111).aspx)) and what if they keep on creating in future.

Comment: Same problem and same solution - deleting the WebMatrix DLLs properly redirected to the login URL.  Still testing this to be 100% sure, but I was able to mark the WebMatrix references so that CopyLocal was set to False.  Ideally, this would prevent them from being recopied to the bin folder.